# Not able to get reference to class file generated in "target" folder of Maven project in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, maven-2, gwt-gin

I am using Google Gin for generating an Event in my GWT project like this:

```
package com.lokur.motd.client.events;

import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.GenEvent;

@GenEvent
public class EditorChange {
}
```

Now, when I compile my project with "mvn clean install -e", it generates required classes viz. EditorChangeEvent.class, EditorChangeEvent$EditorChangeHandler.class, EditorChangeEvent$HasEditorChangeHandlers.class in the target folder of my project.

But, when I try accessing particular generated class e.g. EditorChangeEvent in my project, it gives me compilation error with message:

> "package com.lokur.motd.client.events.EditorChangeEvent
>   does not exist"

...

I don't understand this behavior. Do we need to explicitly add "target" folder of Maven in class-path or somewhere in the pom.xml or something else is causing this?

Here are the plug-ins from maven pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${gwt.plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <runTarget>myMessage/myMessage.html</runTarget>
                            <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
                            <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
                            <!-- <logLevel>INFO" -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 -logLevel "INFO</logLevel> -->
                            <logLevel>ERROR</logLevel>
                            <style>OBF</style>
                            <!-- OBF, PRETTY, DETAILED -->
                            <noServer>false</noServer>
                            <additionalPageParameters>log_level=OFF</additionalPageParameters>
                            <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512m -Ddev.mode=true -DuseCache=false</extraJvmArgs>
                            <extraTestArgs>-Xmx512m -Ddev.mode=true</extraTestArgs>
                            <gwtVersion>${gwtVersion}</gwtVersion>
                            <testFilter>*</testFilter>
                            <hostedWebapp>
                                ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}
                            </hostedWebapp>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>Unzip usp Config &amp; Env Modules</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>com.dig.configs</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>common-configs</artifactId>
                                            <version>${commonConfigs.version}</version>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/tmp</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>usp-env</artifactId>
                                            <version>${pom.version}</version>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/tmp</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>Copy Config, Env Modules</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <copy todir="${basedir}/target/myMessage/WEB-INF/classes/config" overwrite="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
                                            <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/tmp/config">
                                                <include name="**" />
                                            </fileset>
                                            <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/tmp/env">
                                                <include name="**" />
                                            </fileset>
                                        </copy>
                                        <copy todir="${basedir}/target/myMessage/WEB-INF/classes/config" overwrite="true" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
                                            <fileset dir="../config/test" includes="**" />
                                        </copy>
                                        <copy file="${basedir}/../config/usp-app-config.xml" todir="${basedir}/target/myMessage/WEB-INF/classes/config" />
                                        <copy file="${basedir}/../usp-env/src/test/env/usp-app-config.properties" todir="${basedir}/target/myMessage/WEB-INF/classes" />
                                        <copy file="${basedir}/../usp-env/src/test/env/app-config.properties" todir="${basedir}/target/myMessage/WEB-INF/classes" />
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'try accessing'?  Do you mean from your IDE?

Comment: @Nick Holt: Yes. Accessing in some other Class file with in same project in order to create instance of it or for some other purpose..

Comment: And what Maven plugin are you using to generate the classes?

Comment: @Nick Holt: I am not an expert in Maven. Is there any such plugin for generating classes? Could you please give an example...

Comment: You said your Maven build is generating `EditorChangeEvent`, etc - it won't do that be default, normally you'd need to add a plugin - what plugin has been added to your pom.xml?

Comment: @NickHolt: Added plugins from pom.xml in above post. Please have a look.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45815/discussion-between-akshay-lokur-and-nick-holt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the version of GWT supported by our project.
It did not support @GenEvent as the project was not configured to use Gin. So, created Event and Handler classses manually instead of relying on Gin's annotations. Now, it works well. Closing this thread.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar enough with GWT to know if it's that plug that's generating the `EditorChangeEvent` classes but I'd guess it is.

That said, I am however all too familiar with both IntelliJ and Maven.  I can therefore explain how this problem can arise and how to solve it.

If you're going to try to build everything as a single project then you need to find the source files for the `EditorChangeEvent` classes.  It's common for plugins that generate classes to put the source for those classes in `target/generated-sources` but I can't say for sure in the case of GWT (sometimes it's an option on the plugin to indicate whether the source is kept or not).  If this is the case, the plugin should have added a *compile source root* to the Maven project.  IntelliJ will recognise this and mark the `target/generated-sources` directory a *source root* in the IntelliJ project.  If the `target/generated-sources` directory exists but hasn't been automatically marked as a *source root* you can do this by right-clicking the directory and selecting *Mark Directory As*.

The other possiblity is that the source never exists.  If this is the case then you going to have to break you project in two - one project containing the generated classes and one containing the classes that use the generated classes.  Obviously this second project depends on the first using Maven's dependency mechanism.

Comment: I saw in the target folder, but there is no "generated-sources" folder inside it. Also, in my IntelliJ IDE, I do not see "target" folder present. Though it is there on file system.

Comment: IntelliJ, rightly, hides the target folder from you - it would have been displayed if a *compile source root* had been added within the `target` directory by the plugin.  Given it's not there, I think you'll have to split your project.

Comment: Added one more related question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326341/maven-is-generating-gin-java-source-files-in-the-target-classes-directory

Answer (score -1):

http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html
says

**generateDirectory**

> Folder where generated-source will be created (automatically added to
>   compile classpath). ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/gwt

So Maven should be able to compile your project correctly.
However as Nick point target/generated-sources/gwt included as a source directory in your IDE you will have compilation problems.

You need to update your question with more specific details as you have not been clear exactly where in the target folder the classes are generated; or what is giving you compilation errors (Maven or your IDE - and which IDE are you using)

Comment: I added below plugins: 
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
and
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
So, now maven is generating "generated-sources" folder in target dir.

But, it now generates same Java source files in classes/target/ as well as in "generated-sources" folder. Thus, getting compilation error. See my second comment below..

Comment: I mean to say,
two EditorChangeEvent.java files are getting generated.
One in “generated-sources” folder and another in "target/classes/<..package..>" folder.

Thus, causing below compilation failure:

.../target/<package>/events/EditorChangeEvent.java:[9,7] duplicate class: <package>.EditorChangeEvent

Comment: Added one more related question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326341/maven-is-generating-gin-java-source-files-in-the-target-classes-directory

Comment: Please update your question with the correct information instead of in these comments.
Is your project open source that can be looked at?
You need to apply standard debugging techniques to solve your problems. Start by removing everything from your Maven pom.xml and then adding things back in one at a time. You will find where the culprit is.