# Why is Gin generating source files in the "target/classes" directory?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-2, gwt-gin

I am using Maven to build my GWT project. I am using [Gin](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) to generate some boilerplate code:

```
package com.lokur.motd.client.events;

import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.annotation.GenEvent;

@GenEvent
public class EditorChange {
}
```

But, when I run "mvn clean install" command, Maven is generating Gin related Java source in the `target/classes/com/lokur/motd/client/events` directory. Why are there `.java` files going into the `classes` directory?

I'm using the Maven plug-ins below to generate Java source in the `target/generated-sources` folder:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>target/generated-sources/apt</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In this case, two `EditorChangeEvent.java` files are getting generated: one in `generated-sources` folder; another in `target/classes/<..package..>` folder.
Thus, causing below compilation failure:

```
duplicate class:
com.lokur.motd.client.events.EditorChangeEvent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though could not make out why the "Java Source files" were going into the "classes" directory, the issue was with the version of GWT supported by our project.
It did not support @GenEvent as the project was not configured to use Gin. So, created Event and Handler classes manually instead of relying on Gin's annotations. Now, it works well. Closing this thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the org.bsc.maven.maven-processor-plugin and the compiler plugin are generating the (same) sources to different folders. The solution is to disable one processor. In my solution I disabled the org.bsc.maven.maven-processor-plugin [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28051289/1469540).